# Passing data between controllers ABC, from C to A

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Consider three different controllers A, B and C where A is initial controller in Navigation Controller.

Now I push to B and then push to C.

```
A --> B --> C
```

Then I want to go from C to A. How can I go there with a single push and animation. I guess the way would be finding the controller A from the navigation stack and call `popToController` method. Let me know If any other better way.

Now main question is how can I pass the data from `C --> A`.
If it's from `B --> A` I could use the delegation. But for `C --> A` what could be done to use the delegation?

I do have workaround by using observer, singleton, reactive patterns. But I would like to know if any better way can be used.

Comment: self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

Comment: If you want to pass data with delegate from c-> a then you can create two protocols one will pass data from c->b and other will pass data from b->a. Why? Because your A has ref of B not of C (A is pushing B); so you can't directly call delegate from c->a

Comment: Use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15839298/5391914) for unwinding to your A view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple ways to achieve this functionality.
Once can be get you VC from list and pop to it.

```
let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers ;
    for aViewController in viewControllers {
        if let controllerA =  aViewController as? AViewController) {
           controllerA.data = self.data               
           self.navigationController?.popToViewController(controllerA, animated: true);
        }
    }
```

Also you might be interested in [unwind segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them). [Here](https://chrisrisner.com/Unwinding-with-iOS-and-Storyboards) is a nice example too.

Comment: My actual question is about passing the data. I know about this method to pop to the controller A.

Comment: have a look at unwind segue.

Comment: I want to do it without using unwind segues.

Comment: what if you pass delegate reference of A->B then B->C?

Comment: Can you give an example how can I do it?

Comment: @ParthAdroja The only reason not to use unwind segues would be that you are not using storyboard. If thats the case the give delegate pattern a try. Here is an [example](https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef)

Comment: This could be a workaround, not sure how well it will work.
 
BClass  *bVC = [[BClass alloc] init];
bVC .Adelegate = self; and then moving to C.
CClass  *cVC = [[CClass alloc] init];
cVC .delegate = Adelegate ;
something like that.

Comment: @ParthAdroja Updated to allow you to send data from C to A

Answer (score 0):

> You can achieve this via this approach, it will work 100%

```
for item in self.navigationController?.viewControllers ?? [UIViewController]() {
        if item is FirstVC, let vc = item as? FirstVC {
            vc.data = ThirdVC.data //3rd vc data assign to 1st vc
            vc.callAnyMethodOfFirstVC()
            self.navigationController?.popToViewController(item, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

For passing data from C --> A use singleton pattern. any data you want to pass save in variable using singleton pattern and then use

```
 self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

and now you can access data where you want.
hope its help

Comment: No, Singleton are really not design for that.

Comment: then what is suitable for passing data?? @CZ54

Comment: You can either use the Delegate pattern or you can look through NavigationController stack, as suggested above. What if you go again to C after A ? You are stucked with your singleton :)

Comment: how can I stucked when I go again C After A?? @CZ54

Comment: The Singleton will contains old values